Получить интервал, перекрывающий максимальное количество других интервалов. Java
Нужно написать программу на Java, которая выдает границы нового интервала, который перекрывает максимальное количество других интервалов. Например, для интервалов [1, 4], [2, 6], [3, 5], [7, 8], новый интервал будет [2, 4].
Мой код работает, но вывод неверный. Для указанного примера мой вывод [3,4], тогда как должно быть [2,4]. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка.
public static int[] findMaxOverlapInterval(List intervals) {

 List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Interval interval : intervals) {
        events.add(new Event(interval.start, true));
        events.add(new Event(interval.end, false));
    }
    Collections.sort(events);
    int maxOverlaps = 0;
    int currentOverlaps = 0;
    int maxOverlapStart = -1;
    int maxOverlapEnd = -1;
    for (Event event : events) {
        if (event.isStart) {
            currentOverlaps++;
            if (currentOverlaps > maxOverlaps) {
                maxOverlaps = currentOverlaps;
                maxOverlapStart = event.time;
            }
        } else {
            if (currentOverlaps == maxOverlaps) {
                maxOverlapEnd = event.time;
            }
            currentOverlaps--;
        }
    }
    return new int[]{maxOverlapStart, maxOverlapEnd};
}


Почему должно быть 2..4? 3..4 отвечает условию. Может, ещё что-то недосказано?

Судя по коду, класс Event реализует интерфейс Comparable, как именно это сделано?

MBo, согласен, 3..4 должно подходить по логике, но там тесты, по которым именно так: 2..4.

Nowhere Man  public class Event implements Comparable {
int time;
boolean isStart;
Event(int time, boolean isStart) {
    this.time = time;
    this.isStart = isStart;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Event other) {
    if (this.time == other.time) {
        // Start events come before end events if they are at the same time
        return this.isStart ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return Integer.compare(this.time, other.time);
}

}

@user607266 Можете привести точное условие задачи?

Чем плох интервал [1, 8], который пересекается со всеми отрезками?

@MBo Дан массив интервалов, где каждый интервал представлен двумя числами [start, end], которые обозначают начало и конец интервала. Требуется найти границы нового интервала, который перекрывает максимальное количество других интервалов.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy
Интервалы должны пересекаться

@MBo есть тест, который должен быть пройден Test
public void whenIntervalsOverlapThenFindMaxOverlapInterval() {
List intervals = new ArrayList<>();
intervals.add(new Interval(1, 4));
intervals.add(new Interval(2, 6));
intervals.add(new Interval(3, 5));
intervals.add(new Interval(7, 8));
    int[] result = Main.findMaxOverlapInterval(intervals);
    assertThat(result).containsExactly(2, 4);
}


В интервале 2..4 присутствует два подынтервала, причём первый покрывает только два из исходных, а второй - три. Поэтому постановка задачи и ответ на тест весьма сомнительны. И вариант Станислава тоже не противоречит формальному условию.

var start = events.stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.isStart)
    .max(x -> x.time);
    
var end = events.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.isStart)
    .min(x -> x.time);

Результат [starrt -1, end + 1].
